# finding an injective function between real numbers to prove equal cardinality

Tags: functions, cardinals

A problem in discrete math states that we need to prove that $(0,2010)$ has the same cardinality as $(0,\infty)$. The suggested solution is to find an injective function from $(0,2010)$ to $(0,\infty)$ and vice versa. I thought of the following function: $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$$
however the suggested function in the solution is: $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2010}$$
Why isn't my function enough why do we have to substract the $\frac{1}{2010}$ part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function establishes a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $(\color{red}1, \infty)$ - not what you are asked to show. But if you subtract that annoying $\color{red}1$, i.e. if you consider $\dfrac 1 x - 1$, then you get your desired bijection.

I don't get the $2010$ part and I wouldn't bother with it.

Comment: Why are you saying that my function goes to $(1,\infty)$? If x > 1, then the codomain will be less than 1. x cannot be equal to 1 as this is the domain definition. Lastly if x < 1 then the codomain will be greater than 1.

Comment: @Yos: When $x$ is close to $0$, $\frac 1 x$ is close to $\infty$. With $x$ increasing from $0$ to $1$, $\frac 1 x$ decreases from $\infty$ to $1$, so the range of your function (the codomain) is $(\infty, 1)$, but since we always write intervals with the lower end to the right, the codomain is then written as $(1, \infty)$. Of course, the endpoints $1$ and $\infty$ themselves are not reached, because $x$ does not reach $1$ and, respectively, $0$.

Comment: @Yos: Also note that the solution suggested by the problem is to find an injection between $(0,1)$ and $(0, \infty)$, then to find another one from $(0, \infty)$ to $(0,1)$, and then to apply [Bernstein's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) to these two injections. Really? This would make sense for very complicated sets where bijections are difficult to produce, but in this case coming up with a bijection between the two sets is the most natural thing that one can think of - the proof being that the other answerers independently thought of this, too.

Comment: Apologies I made a mistake in the question, it's from $(0,2010)$ to $(1,\infty)$

Comment: @Yos: No, I believe that the range of values is $(0, \infty)$, not $(1, \infty)$ (as you write in the comment above).

Comment: for example if we take $f(2000)=\frac{1}{2000}$ it is close to 0. If we take $f(0.00001)=\frac{1}{0.00001}$ which is close to infinity. This means that the function covers the codomain from $(0,\infty)$, no?

Comment: @Yos: Let's not turn this into an endless discussion: "close" to $0$ means "arbitrarily close" to $0$, or, equivalently, "infinitely close" to $0$. But can $\frac 1 x$ go lower than $\frac 1 {2010}$? For instance, can $\frac 1 x$ reach the value $10^{-10}$? No, it can't, because $x$ would have to be $10^{10}$ which is outside of $(0, 2010)$. So $\frac 1 x$ cannot get infinitely close to $0$, and that's why you subtract $\frac 1 {2010}$ from it: the new function gets as close to $0$ as you want, a feat that $\frac 1 x$ was not capable of, stopping at $\frac 1 {2010}$ and not getting any lower.

Answer (score 0):

You function shows that $]0,1[$ has the same cardinality as $]1,+\infty[$, $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}-1$ seems like a good answer, and $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}-2010$ would show that $]0,1[$ is bigger than $]0,+\infty[$ (it spans a bigger interval) which is fine since you also have the inclusion the other way.

I don't know why they retracted $\frac{1}{2010}$, it doesn't show anything (it shows it for $]1-\frac{1}{2010},+\infty[$, but that is not the topic discussed here)

Answer (score 0):

Your function bijectively maps $(0, 1)$ to $(1, \infty)$, not to $(0, \infty)$.  So, I would put
$$
f(x) = {1 \over x} - 1.
$$
No idea about the $2010$ denominator.